# Gradle javadoc plugin errors

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle task like this:

```
task api(type: Javadoc) {
    group = 'Documentation'
    description = 'Generates the Javadoc API documentation.'
    title = "${rootProject.description} ${version} API"
    options.memberLevel = org.gradle.external.javadoc.JavadocMemberLevel.PROTECTED
    options.author = true
    options.header = rootProject.description
    options.overview = 'src/api/overview.html'

    source = sourceSets.main.allJava
    classpath = project.sourceSets.main.compileClasspath
    destinationDir = new File(buildDir, "api")
}
```

but when I run the command - gradle api I get the following error.

[ERROR] [system.err] javadoc: error - Error while reading file overview.html
[QUIET] [system.out] 1 error
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: FAILED

Any idea why this is failing to read the overview.html file?

It appears that this error message is misleading. I tried the task with a non-existent file and still getting the same error (with the file name changed in the error message)

Appreciate the help!!

Comment: *I tried the task with a non-existent file and still getting the same error (with the file name changed in the error message)*: so, the problem is probably that `'src/api/overview.html'` does not exist either. I would use the file() method to produce an absolute file path. Note that the javadoc documentation for -overview specifies: *The path/filename is relative to the -sourcepath*.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. When I changed options.overview to file() it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Gradle tasks not able to find the location of overview.html file

Just add this property in build.grdle

```
javadoc {      
    options.overview = "src/main/java/overview.html"
}
```

and run   **./gradlew javadoc**

It  executed successfully for me