# Add parameter to a Gradle plugin

Tags: java, gradle, liferay, gradle-plugin

I'm new to Gradle and I'm working on a Liferay project. I'm trying to use the Liferay javadoc gradle plugin without success. I'm working on the Liferay IDE (Eclipse) and I already have the javadoc task available to execute. The problem is, after the excution (which completes successfully) I can't find the created docs.

I read the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.javadoc.Javadoc.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.javadoc.Javadoc:destinationDir) which says there is `destinationDir` property but I'm unable to set it using Gradle.

I tried following [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770607/gradle-javadoc-plugin-errors) in order to create a custom Gradle task but without success.

How can I set the `destinationDir` in order to get the generated docs?

**Edit**:

The (automatic generated) `settings.gradle` is:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.gradle.plugins.workspace", version: "1.5.0"
        classpath group: "net.saliman", name: "gradle-properties-plugin", version: "1.4.6"
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://cdn.lfrs.sl/repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/groups/public"
       }
    }
}

apply plugin: "net.saliman.properties"

apply plugin: "com.liferay.workspace"
```

I'm pretty sure that `com.liferay.gradle.plugins.workspace` includes the javadoc plugin. Furthermore, Liferay also automatically creates an empty `build.gradle` where I put:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

task api(type: Javadoc) {
    source = sourceSets.main.allJava
    destinationDir = new File(buildDir, "/api")
}
```

Launching the `api` Gradle task the javadoc plugin is not executed

Comment: Can you share your `build.gradle` file? Because the answer is in the question you referenced, the paramater `destinationDir` it's defined at the last line of the task: `destinationDir = new File(buildDir, "api")`

Comment: Hi Eduardo, I tried this:
apply plugin: 'java'

task api(type: Javadoc) {
    destinationDir = new File(buildDir, "/api")
}
but launching this task doesn't execute the javadoc plugin

Comment: I don't know liferay, so I tried only your `build.gradle` configurations (I've ignored `settings.gradle`), and works fine, the docs are on `build/api`.